# Random byte being added when using string()

Tags: go

I am attempting to XOR two values. If I do I can get the right result, however, using string() on it results in a random byte being added to it!

Can anyone explain this?

Here's a playground: http://play.golang.org/p/tIOOjqo_Fe

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, you have:

```
z := 175 // 0xaf
```

That is the unicode code point for the character: `¯`

The following line of code will then take the value and treat it as a unicode code point (rune) and turn it into a utf-8 encoded string:

```
out := string(z)
```

In utf-8 encoding, that character would be represented by two bytes: `[]byte(0xc2, 0xaf)`

So, the bytes you see are the Go string's utf-8 encoding.

Comment: That's exactly what I had come up with after some more digging around. Thanks for the confirmation! :D